# ARC strange behaviour copies value to child view instead of retaining it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I have a problem. It looks like ARC synchronizes my property with child class.
Here's the code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"tableView:didSelectRow: %i", indexPath.row);

    JobDetailViewController *jdViewController=[[JobDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JobDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    jdViewController.delegate=self;
    [jdViewController setJob:[[jobsWithPipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] job]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:jdViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that `jdViewController's` job property synchronizes with `[[jobsWithPipes objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] job]`. All properties are `nonatomic, retain`.
When I'm changing the `NSNumber* foreman` property in `jdViewController` the new value copies to parent view controller. Why? It looks like ARC uses copy instead of retain on this objects. Help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your understanding of `retain` and `copy` is backwards.

With a `retain` property, when you assign a value to it, it gets a pointer to the same object that you assigned. So if you modify one object, it modifies the other.

With a `copy` property, when you assign a v alue to it, it gets a copy of the object. So the objects will be identical, but distinct. When you modify one object, it **won`t** modify the other.

Comment: `[copy setPicture:[[UIImage allocWithZone: zone] initWithCGImage: [self.picture CGImage]]];` this is a part of code in `copyWithZone`. Is it right?

Comment: I have no idea—I would need way more context. Also, `copy` is a terrible name for an object.